# How to pass an array of size changing structures into a glsl shader

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, glsl, shading

In order to add dynamic lighting to my application, I was thinking that I could represent each shadow casting object as an array of floats (every 3 floats is a vector and so every 9 floats is a triangle). And so, in order to cast ALL possible shadows, I need an array of these arrays (if this was C++ I would have done an array of vectors).

Is there a way to construct somehting similar in a glsl shader, throught either SSBOs or uniforms?

And if not, how could I pass this information. The problem here is that I don't know how big the number of triangles per shading object is, so I have no way of determining a constant sized structure to make my array of solid objects.

Comment: How else would you do dynamic shadows then?

Comment: Shadowmaps is todays most widely used technique (at least in games, there is active research for incorporating soft-shadows, etc.). Shadow Volumes are another technique. Should be fairly easy to find a OpenGL tutorial if you google for them.

Comment: Textures won't work, they require both dymensions to be the same, which is exactly my problem

Comment: Since when do Texture require both dimensions to be the same? You can create texture of any size you want.

Comment: Sorry, I mean that if you have a 2D texture of mxn dimensions, then the second dimension is always n, and I don't remember textures allowing for arbitrary changes across their second dimensions as you iterate throught them.

Comment: @BDL shadow mapping has artefacts and would actually be slower than what I am planning on doing for this

Comment: There is no fully dynamic buffer in OpenGL (as their also isn't in C++ or anywhere else). If the size changes, you'll have to allocate memory. What you can do is to allocate enough memory for all situations but not use all of it. You can, for example, have an additional uniform storing up to which row the texture is filled. (The same things also apply to SSBOs or any other buffer).

Comment: If you find a method for rendering shadows without any artifacts which is in addition faster than traditional techniques (which I doubt, but who knows), let me know, I'd be highly interested how you do it. My current guess is that you're going to use some kind of ray-tracing technique, but I'm fairly sure that this won't work out. I really don't wont to discourage you from trying, just want to make you aware that you might be wasting a lot of time.

Comment: Well I know it's faster, but it's not general. Basically, I am working on an engine that has the convention of being voxelized, and I know that all static objects are in specific pre-defiined positions, so I can minimize the ray tracing overhead because I can discard the vast majority of triangles before computing ray intersection.

This ends up requiring less operations than rendering the scene twice and then using transformation matrices to do the depth test comparison of shadow mapping.

Comment: Surely you just have a bunch of triangles and the objects don't actually matter?

Comment: The objects matter in the sense that I need packets that are hashed to the voxelized x,y,z coordinates in the world

Comment: Well it sounds like you know what you're doing better than anyone else does. You can use a texture and treat it like a 1D array. Unfortunately 1D textures are quite limited in size (16384 pixels on my PC) so then you map your 1D array back onto a 2D texture.

Comment: @Makogan: "*I know that all static objects are in specific pre-defiined positions,*" Then why do you need this array of arrays?

Comment: I know WHERE they are but I do not know WHAT they are, i.e I know their positions but not their geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking simultaneously too high-level and too low-level. You say that you need a bunch of arrays, but you don't. What you need is a way to get the vertex data for a particular object in the scene. This doesn't have to be encoded as "an array of these arrays" at all.

Instead, encode it as a single massive array of vertex data. Each object has indices that specifies the location in this array for the vertex data.

```
layout(std430) buffer obj_data
{
  uvec2 objects[];
};

layout(std430) buffer vertex_data
{
  vec4 vertices[]; //NEVER use `vec3`s in storage blocks
};
```

`objects` is an array, where each `uvec2` represents a specific object. The `x` component of that `uvec2` is the offset into `vertices` where its vertex data starts. And `y` is the number of vertices to read, starting at `x`.

So `vertices[objects[10].x]` is the first vertex of the data for the object with index 10.

And BTW:

> if this was C++ I would have done an array of vectors

If this were C++, I'd encode it more or less like I would for GLSL: store all of the vertex data in a single array, and have each object reference its contiguous slice of that array. It's more efficient to access than an array of `vector`, and requires far fewer allocations.